# How to change the color of the text cursor/insertion point in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am using WPF to create some UIs and I changed the main window background color to black. I've managed to change the color of every control in the main window to either transparent or black, which goes for buttons, textblocks, textboxes etc. The problem now is with the textboxes, the text cursor/insertion point is present but is not visible, which is bringing confusion when trying write text inside the textbox. Is there a class in the C# library that can allow to customize and change color of the text cursor/insertion point?

I searched for answers on Google, but I'm only getting results of how to customize the text cursor on Windows rather.

Comment: [TextBoxBase.CaretBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.caretbrush) is what you are looking for.